# Bash remove substring in file from string

Tags: string, bash, replace

I've one string like this:

```
myString='value1|value57|value31|value21'
```

and I've a file, called values_to_remove.txt containing a list of values, one per line, in this way

**values_to_remove.txt**

```
value1
value31
```

In bash, how can I remove the values contained in "values_to_remove.txt" from the string, taking into account that the values are separated by pipe and of course if I remove a value I have to removee also the preceding and the following pipe if any.

I've achieved this in python and called the python script from bash, but I need to do this directly in bash with one line command, rather than small script, otherwise I can already use my little python script.

That's the python code

```
myString = 'value1|value2|value3|value4'
arrString = myString.split("|")

with open("myfile.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
   for l in file:
       if  l in arrString:
           arrString.remove(l)

myNewString = "|".join(arrString)
```

Note that:  the values separeted by pipe can be anything string.

Thank you

Comment: I've done this in python and called the python script from bash, but I need to do this directly in bash

Comment: I've update the question and edited the wrong part

Comment: @Inian meant update the post with the python code you wrote to achieve that.

Comment: Added the python code, but I don't understand you request. Did you think I was lying?

Comment: @user2548436: It is nothing as such, it is just that, people will be more receptive to your question, if they see some efforts/code made to solve the problem, rather than blatantly asking for a code request

Comment: Ok, now I've got the point

Comment: also, people will then try to mold your solution to get you to answer and in the way suggest you improvement if any. :)

Comment: @user2548436: Also asking for one line code is not a good thing. See if the problem is solved, properly readable and covers all cases. anubhava's answer could very well written in one line? Are you looking for just representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v str="$myString" 'BEGIN {
   n = split(str, a, /\|/)
}
{
   val[$1]
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      if (!(a[i] in val))
         s = (s == "" ? "" : s "|") a[i]
   print s
}' values_to_remove.txt
```

```
value57|value21
```

- This `awk` first uses a `split` function to `split` input string on `|`
- It stores all values to be removed in another array `val`
- In the end block it loops through split array and builds a string if value is not found in to-be-removed array.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava for your time. Unfortunatelly I've update the question after you've already reply because my need is for one line command. Do you know how to do?

Comment: This is one line only but I formatted it si to make it readable. You can keep this in single line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `bash` solution (The `if` statement is a runtime optimization to skip the repacement in case of no match, thanks @Inian):

```
for val in value1 value31; do
    if [[ "$mystring" =~ \|$val|$val\| ]]; then
        mystring=${mystring/$BASH_REMATCH/}     
    fi
done
```

This looks in pure bash for the first regular expression that matches either `|value` or `value|` and removes it. Note you can match both at the same times because then you will delete too many separators. If there is a chance there are no separators you need to use `?` after each pipe (maybe just the second one is enough).

You can also avoid regular expressions and just attempt to delete both a prior and a posterior pipe:

```
for val in value1 value31; do 
    mystring=${mystring/|$val/};
    mystring=${mystring/$val|/}; 
done
```

All of these can be written on one line if you really need to:

```
 for val in value1 value31; do [[ "$mystring" =~ \|$val|$val\| ]]; mystring=${mystring/$BASH_REMATCH/}; done
```

Comment: Correct. I would say this is a run-time optimization.

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Define the location of the values-to-be-removed file
: ${PATH_TO_FILE:=${1:-"./values_to_remove.txt"}}

# Define the string we will be working with
: ${MY_STRING:=${2:-"value1|value57|value31|value21"}}

# Process all entries in PATH_TO_FILE, one by one
while read -r substring || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

  # Remove "substring|" from the beginning of MY_STRING
  MY_STRING=${MY_STRING#${substring}|}

  # Remove "|substring" from the rest of MY_STRING
  MY_STRING=${MY_STRING//|${substring}}

done < "${PATH_TO_FILE}"

# Return the results
echo ${MY_STRING}
```

**Why do we...**

- Use `${VAR_NAME:=${1:-"DEFAULT_VALUE"}}` notation - To allow the user to customise script's inputs either via environment variables or script arguments. Basically, this notation says:

  - If VAR_NAME environment variable exists, then use it;
  - If VAR_NAME doesn't exist, then set VAR_NAME to the value of the first argument to the script;
  - If the first argument doesn't exist either, then set VAR_NAME to the DEFAULT_VALUE.
- Use `read -r substring || [[ -n "$line" ]]` to read the file? – `read` allows us to read content of `./values_to_remove.txt` file, line by line. The `[[ -n "$line" ]]` bit is there to catch the last line in the file if it doesn't end with a newline.

**References**:

- [Assign a default value in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#assign_a_default_value)
- [Return default value in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value)
- [Bash substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)
- [Bash search and replace](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace)